# google analytics stopped tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

i've been fighting with this problem from a while now. I think it all started when i've added my website to google webmaster's tool: at some point I started receiving an alert saying my website was missing the tracking code, but actually it was there, and even though it said it was missing, i still got my analytics stats.

[image]

at that time, the code was include in a .js file containing all of my javascript. it was included right before the `</body>` tag and it was loaded this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = "js/build/production.min.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }

    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else
        window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
</body>
```

i've found this script on some blog (http://www.giftofspeed.com/defer-javascripts/) and I use this to defer javascript loading to make the page to load faster.

at some point i thought deferring the ga code was the problem (as it's all in that `production.min.js` file) so i've moved the ga code outside of that. and now it's like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = "js/build/production.min.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }

    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else
        window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
<script>
//my google analytics code here
</script>
</body>
```

once I did this, the alert got solved BUT the tracking is not happening anymore.

[image]

I've been using GA from ages and I never had problems like these. What could this be? I feel like i've tried it all.

Answer (score 0):

### Approach for modern browsers

https://github.com/jfriend00/docReady/blob/master/docready.js

### Your customisation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = "js/build/production.min.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }

(function(funcName, baseObj) {
    "use strict";
    // The public function name defaults to window.docReady
    // but you can modify the last line of this function to pass in a different object or method name
    // if you want to put them in a different namespace and those will be used instead of 
    // window.docReady(...)
    funcName = funcName || "docReady";
    baseObj = baseObj || window;
    var readyList = [];
    var readyFired = false;
    var readyEventHandlersInstalled = false;

    // call this when the document is ready
    // this function protects itself against being called more than once
    function ready() {
        if (!readyFired) {
            // this must be set to true before we start calling callbacks
            readyFired = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < readyList.length; i++) {
                // if a callback here happens to add new ready handlers,
                // the docReady() function will see that it already fired
                // and will schedule the callback to run right after
                // this event loop finishes so all handlers will still execute
                // in order and no new ones will be added to the readyList
                // while we are processing the list
                readyList[i].fn.call(window, readyList[i].ctx);
            }
            // allow any closures held by these functions to free
            readyList = [];
        }
    }

    function readyStateChange() {
        if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
            ready();
        }
    }

    // This is the one public interface
    // docReady(fn, context);
    // the context argument is optional - if present, it will be passed
    // as an argument to the callback
    baseObj[funcName] = function(callback, context) {
        // if ready has already fired, then just schedule the callback
        // to fire asynchronously, but right away
        if (readyFired) {
            setTimeout(function() {callback(context);}, 1);
            return;
        } else {
            // add the function and context to the list
            readyList.push({fn: callback, ctx: context});
        }
        // if document already ready to go, schedule the ready function to run
        // IE only safe when readyState is "complete", others safe when readyState is "interactive"
        if (document.readyState === "complete" || (!document.attachEvent && document.readyState === "interactive")) {
            setTimeout(ready, 1);
        } else if (!readyEventHandlersInstalled) {
            // otherwise if we don't have event handlers installed, install them
            if (document.addEventListener) {
                // first choice is DOMContentLoaded event
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready, false);
                // backup is window load event
                window.addEventListener("load", ready, false);
            } else {
                // must be IE
                document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", readyStateChange);
                window.attachEvent("onload", ready);
            }
            readyEventHandlersInstalled = true;
        }
    }
})("downloadJSAtOnload", window);
// modify this previous line to pass in your own method name 
// and object for the method to be attached to

</script>
```

Comment: should this solve it? so should i put my ga code back in production.min.js?

Comment: I use this solution for different analytics project and it works perfectly. The previouse solution is getting old and is not working in many new browsers, especially with blink rendering engine.

Comment: does it matter if in that file i have all my other js files?

Comment: I think there is no problem in it. GA is fully asynchronouse and independent on other scripts.